# Flutter : How to align differently two items in a column

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a column made like this with flutter :

```dart
Container(
      width: width,
      height: width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            FittedBox(child: Icon(Icons.cancel, size: 40)),
            FittedBox(child: Text("data")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

But I want the `Icon` to be perfectly centered and the text to be aligned on the bottom of the orange container. Is there a way to do that without using stack ? As you can see in the image below, both icon and text are aligned to the center, so the icon is not perfectly centered.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"Is there a way to do that without using stack ?"* - yes, `CustomMultiChildLayout`

Comment: Why not use a Stack?

Comment: Can you tell your except design?

Comment: Stack is the best way to go for your use-case.

Comment: @Rukka Because I know how to do it with a stack, but I was wondering if it was possible to do it more simply, like with a column specific parameter or something like that. But I'm gonna use a stack I think, because it looks like `pskink` answer is possible but harder to implement than a stack.

Comment: @SimonB with `Stack` you cannot align text's top to icons's bottom as shown in the image you posted (you can only align text's bottom to whole orange container bottom) - however this can be done with `CustomMultiChildLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally chosen to use the Stack, because it was in fact the easiest way to do what I wanted to do... Here is how I've done it :

```dart
SizedBox(
          width: width,
          height: width,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                      child: Icon(Icons.cancel, size: 40))),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 3),
                    child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        child: Text(
                          "data",
                        )),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

With the stack and the align, it matches what I wanted to do...
Thanks for the help of everyone that answered this post.

Answer (score 0):

Align `widget` could help.
Let your `Column` take its maximum height (determined by parent `Container`) and wrap the icon with `Expanded` or `Flexible` then wrap your elements with `Align` with the appropriate alignment values.

Btw, This doesn't achieve **perfect** centering, but it gets as close to it as small your text is.

```
Container(
    width: width,
    height: width,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.amber,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Flexible(
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Icon(Icons.cancel, size: 40))),
        Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: Text("data")),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: Container()),
        Expanded(
            child: Center(
                child: FittedBox(child: Icon(Icons.cancel, size: 40)))),
        Expanded(
            child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: FittedBox(
              child: Text(
            "data",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
          )),
        )),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks, that is clever, but that code is not that "clean". But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).